# Can the mac's bluetooth name be changed without changing the computer/network name/hostname?

Tags: bluetooth

I have some bluetooth headphones which read out the name of the devices it connects to. My corporate MacBook Pro has a specific hostname, so when I connect to the headphones I hear a really long, random alphanumeric string.

If I was able to change the Computer name in the Sharing preferences pane it will rename the Bluetooth name, but is there a way to rename the bluetooth name only, leaving the computer name and network hostname alone?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Had the same problem, this worked for me:

You can rename the **LocalHostName** separately from the **Computer Name**, which should give you the desired result, and shouldn't mess with any network settings.

Under *System Preferences* -> *Sharing*, click the *Edit* button to the lower right of the *Computer Name* field. Here you can enter a different local hostname, and leave the computer name set to whatever you want the Bluetooth name to be.

If you explicitly need to set a hostname, you can also do that from Terminal, by entering:

```
scutil --set HostName yourhostnamehere
```

Before you do that though, you might want to check the current values. You can use these commands for hostname, local hostname, and computer name respectively:

```
scutil --get HostName
scutil --get LocalHostName
scutil --get ComputerName
```

An explanation of each of the properties can be found [here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/10/24/set-the-hostname-computer-name-and-bonjour-name-separately-in-os-x/):

**ComputerName** is the so-called “user-friendly” computer name for a Mac, it’s what will show up on the Mac itself and what will be visible to others when connecting to it over a local network. This is also what’s visible under the Sharing preference panel.

**HostName** is the name assigned to the computer as visible from the command line, and it’s also used by local and remote networks when connecting through SSH and Remote Login.

**LocalHostName** is the name identifier used by Bonjour and visible through file sharing services like AirDrop

Comment: I think this is the closest I'll be able to get. I think it's `ComputerName` which I want to change (my company has set each of the three settings specifically, though). I've added a description of each of the settings to your answer.